# How to let scrapy define working http prefix?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I am running a scraper on a set of domains. The list with domains is provided externally, and a test run with scrapy made clear that for some websites the http prefix is not correctly specified. Some websites throw a DNS error when you try to navigate http://**www**.example.com instead of http://example.com.

I tried to address this by a for loop that generates for each domain the combinations with the most common prefixes (http://www., http://,https://,https://www.). Yet, I found out that this for some websites results in them being scraped twice (with just all duplicate content), which is not only inefficient from my side, but also not inline with web etiquette.

I am having two questions:

- Is this how Scrapy should behave?
- How can I prevent this from happening?

I have seen [How check if website support http, htts and www prefix with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104875/how-check-if-website-support-http-htts-and-www-prefix-with-scrapy), but it feels like a detour, it should be part of Scrapy itself.

Comment: That's not a Scrapy issue: each website may (or may not) redirects you to `https` from `http` (same for `www`). It's all about website configuration settings. And of course `http://example.com` version may be absolutely different from `http://www.example.com` because that's a different domain.

Comment: @gangabass I understand that it is officially a different domain, but I am quite sure that there are no differences in the content displayed between the https and the http domain of my websites. What would be a good way to address this? Writing a first loop in which all the domains are inspected for which prefix is working, and then scrape those? (and then max one per organisation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283240/check-if-two-urls-are-for-the-same-website